# What is wrong with my Java code for entering name, age, and seeing if a person is old enough to do something?

Tags: java, if-statement

What is wrong with my code? The 'if' statement does not seem to be working! I run the program and enter my name and age. I enter an age eligible for using the program but it says I am too young. I coded this and it wont let me use it!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class learning {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        Scanner uI = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
        System.out.print(uI.nextLine());
        System.out.println(", enter your age: ");
        uI.nextInt();
        int person = 10;

        if (person > 10){
            System.out.println("You may use this program!");
        }else{
            System.out.println("You may not use this program. You are too young!");
        }

        uI.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: always post a useful questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    int person = 10;

    if (person > 10){
        System.out.println("You may use this program!");
    }else{
        System.out.println("You may not use this program. You are too young!");
    }
```

you aren't changing the person value at all! It should be always the 10.

Answer (score 3):

You are not assigning `uI.nextInt();` to any int variable. Like :

```
    System.out.println(", enter your age: ");
    int personAge = uI.nextInt();
    int person = 10; // instead use this as constant, public static final int MIN_ALLOWED_AGE = 11;

    if (personAge > person){   // if (personAge >= MIN_ALLOWED_AGE){
        System.out.println("You may use this program!");
    }else{
        System.out.println("You may not use this program. You are too young!");
    }
```

Comment: Thankyou so much! Wow, I posted this 8 minutes ago and I already got 5 answers, all which are correct! I remember learning that, I guess I has a brain malfunction!

Answer (score 1):

Well, right now your if statement is:

```
if (person > 10)
```

When, if you want it to work for ages 10 and older, it should be:

```
if (person >= 10)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thankyou, but I figured this out 2 minutes after I posted. My real problem was not assigning uI.nextInt(); to a variable!

Answer (score 1):

10 is never greater than 10 so your code is not working. do this

```
person>=10
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
public class learning {
   public static void main(String args[]){

    Scanner uI = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
    System.out.print(uI.nextLine());
    System.out.println(", enter your age: ");

    int person = uI.nextInt();

    if (person > 10){
        System.out.println("You may use this program!");
    }else{
        System.out.println("You may not use this program. You are too young!");
    }

    uI.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first you're assigning the variable a static value on line 12, you're using the ">" operator when you should be using >=. and finally, you might consider assigning the result of uI.nextInt() to person before the test instead of setting it to a static value.

Comment: Thanks @HarryJoy, fat fingers